# Where should a theoretic question about Eclipse (IDE) workspaces go?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, guidelines

Which SE site would be best to ask a theoretic question about workspace management in Eclipse?

Question I intend to ask:

> What is the rule to create a workspace? Does everyone create a workspace for each release and include the same project in different workspaces? Or do you stick to one workspace just updating the code?

Comment: Would such question be appropriate for [programmers.se]? Can you provide an example of what kind of questions you mean?

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without knowing the specific context.

Comment: If you add more context to the question, be a little more specific I'd try on Programmers. Although it may be a good fit for programmers be careful not to ask for opinions, ask for best practices but keeping in mind that they need to be supported by facts/analysis. You really need to add more context to your question because some may vote to close as too broad as it stands. that's only my opinion so I'm actually a bit keen to see what others say.

Comment: @All atleast I get SO isn't the correct place to ask this question. As per the accepted answer from the post of which this is said to be a duplicate, it says _'SO Does not welcome subjective questions (any more).'_

Answer (score 2):

Last time I checked Eclipse was a software development tool. Looking at the [SO /about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page we see

[image: SO Aks]

So it looks on the face of it that SO is the right place to ask but whoa what's this

[image: SO Don't ask]

As your question is polling and asking for opinions so sadly SO isn't the right place.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the rule to create a workspace?

This is opinion-based. There is no single rule to follow. The companies could in some cases have internal rules, you could ask about that rules on [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com).

> Does everyone create a workspace for each release and include the same
>   project in different workspaces?

This is a poll question, so it doesn't fit to any site.

You could be more specific, for example ask about the impact of opening many projects in single workspace on performance. It would be a bit too broad, but would at least fit StackOverflow or SuperUser.

Comment: @Yannis lol good catch! Actually site for discussing Workspace isn't a bad idea, people can rant about their limited space and how to make it bigger and more comfortable. ;-)